# 400 Error on KMS Permissions when creating a VM in GCP using a custom service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-cloud-kms

I'm using Terraform to create a VM instance and Network, Compute Disk, that gets attached to said instance, a Snapshot of that disk and a KMS Key Ring and key to encrypt the data.

I authenticate to GCP using a Service Account created by myself, using the following block:

`credentials = file("gcp-account.json")`

The account has the following permissions:

- Cloud KMS Admin
- Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter
- Compute Admin
- Compute Network Admin
- Editor

Then, in the `google_compute_snapshot` and `google_compute_disk` blocks i provide the `kms_key_self_link` and Service Account to encrypt the data using the newly created KMS Key and my custom Service Account for the request:

```
kms_key_self_link       = var.kms_key_selflink
kms_key_service_account = var.service_account
```

I do the same thing in the `google_compute_instance` block and provide the `kms_key_self_link` in `boot_disk` and `attached_disk` and also specify that the VM should use the custom Service Account for requests:

```
  service_account {
    email  = var.service_account
    scopes = []
  }
```

Then, upon running `terraform apply` i get the following error:

> Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Cloud KMS error
> when using key
> projects/{project name}/locations/{location}/keyRings/{key ring name}/cryptoKeys/{key name}: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied on
> resource
> 'projects/{project name}/locations/{location}/keyRings/{key ring name}/cryptoKeys/{key name}:' (or it may not exist)., kmsPermissionDenied

Which gets resolved when i grant the

> roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter

permission to the Compute Engine Service Agent, then the script runs just fine.

```
data "google_iam_policy" "kms_key_encrypt_decrypt" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"

    members = ["serviceAccount:service{{PROJECT_NUMBER}}@computesystem.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
  }
}

resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_policy" "crypto_key" {
  crypto_key_id = google_kms_crypto_key.key.id
  policy_data   = data.google_iam_policy.kms_key_encrypt_decrypt.policy_data
}
```

I would however prefer all my resources using just my custom Service Account for requests and not having the default Compute Engine Service Agent involved in any way.

I've checked, which roles the Compute Engine Service Agent has assigned, there's only one:

> Compute Engine Service Agent

and assigned exactly the same role to my custom Service Account.
This didn't help. Later I've noticed, that the problem only occurs within the `boot_disk` of the VM:

```
  boot_disk {
    kms_key_self_link = var.kms_key_selflink

    initialize_params {
      image = var.vm_image
      type  = var.gce_disk_type
    }
  }
```

When i comment out the `kms_key_self_link` in the `boot_disk` block, the other resources (Snapshot, Compute Disk, attached disk),  which also make use of `kms_key_self_link` and the custom Service Account get provisioned without any problems. If i leave the `kms_key_self_link` parameter in `boot_disk`, the problem persists and i need to specify the default agent to make it resolved.

Is there a way to get all my resources provisioned with just the use of the custom Service Account without any involvement of the default Compute Engine Service Agent and I'm just missing something in my script or does the default agent need to stay for some operations?

Comment: Per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-managed-encryption, you need to grant permission for the compute engine SA. Note this is different than the default compute engine service account or a custom service account for when you boot your VM. This is the control plane service account.

Comment: Yes, when i grant the necessary permissions to the Compute Engine Service Agent everything is working perfectly fine. I was however curious if it's possible to get everything up&running without modifying or involving the CE SA at all, by assigning the Encrypter/Decrypter permissions to a custom Service Account and associating this custom account with a VM.

Comment: Service Agent accounts are created by Google and manage the control plane. Example create resources for you in your account. You can add/delete roles to the Service Agent but you cannot replace it. Service Agent accounts are used by Google to manage your resources. In your case, you are granting Google privileges to decrypt data on your behalf to create the instance.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B yes, as stated above it's impossible to get some of the resources provisioned without the involvement of the Compute Engine SA, so i granted it the necessary permissions regardless of my custom Service Account.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you did to solve the issue ? Please post it as an answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 2):

So, as it turns out via the provided answers it's not possible to get all the resources provisioned without the involvement of the Compute Engine Service Agent. It must have the

> roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter

role granted, regardless of any other custom Service Accounts used. Here's the policy i use in my Terraform code to grant it the necessary permissions:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "kms_key_encrypt_decrypt" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"

    members = ["serviceAccount:service{{PROJECT_NUMBER}}@computesystem.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
  }
}

resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_policy" "crypto_key" {
  crypto_key_id = google_kms_crypto_key.key.id
  policy_data   = data.google_iam_policy.kms_key_encrypt_decrypt.policy_data
}
```

Thanks to everyone for the answers.